# Thee.js - Creating a perpendicular-parallel opacity falloff material

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I need some help creating a material in Three.js.

What I need is a material with a perpendicular-parallel opacity falloff to the camera viewing direction. So when the viewing direction is perpendicular, the material is 100% transparent. And when the viewing direction is parallel, the material is 100% opaque.

On a sphere this should result in somehting like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0zWP.jpg

I don't really know very much about custom shaders, so I hope someone can help me out writing some code to achieve this.